# Как выбрать ответы на комментарии из монги?

Tags: mongodb

Как, в рамках одной агрегации, получить ответы на комменты?
Пример:

```
{
 "_id": 1,
 "reply_for": null,
 "comment": "комментарий"
},
{
 "_id": 2,
 "reply_for" 1,
 "comment": "Ответ"
}
```

можно-ли вообще это сделать в рамкох одной агрегации, чтобы например на выходе получить

```
{
     "_id": 1,
     "reply_for": null,
     "comment": "комментарий",
     "reply" : [
        {
          "_id": 2,
         "reply_for": 1,
          "comment": "Ответ"
        },
     ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
....
  ['$addFields' =>  ['comment_id' => ['$toString' => '$_id']],
  ['$lookup' => [
     'from' => 'collection',
     'localField' => 'comment_id',
     'foreignField' => 'reply_for',
     'as' => 'reply',
  ]
  ]
....
```